# Best way to return joined table in Sqlite.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

The following code works perfectly and I get exactly what I need, but I'm curious if there is a better way to return a joined table. If you look below, how much code I need to write for the joined "Address" table. I was hoping someone can confirm this is the best way to do this. Thanks!

```
static func findByEntityId(entityId: Int) throws -> [EntityAddress] {
    let query = table.filter(EntityId == entityId).join(AddressDB.table, on: AddressDB.table[Id] == table[AddressId])
    var array = [T]()
    let items = try db.prepare(query)
    for item in items {

        let address = Address(id: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Id]], addressType: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.AddressType]], addressStatus: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.AddressStatus]], address1: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Address1]], address2: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Address2]], city: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.City]], state: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.State]], zip: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Zip]], country: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Country]], latitude: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Latitude]], longitude: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Longitude]], isDeleted: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.IsDeleted]], created: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Created]], createdBy: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.CreatedBy]]!, modified: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.Modified]], modifiedBy: item[AddressDB.table[AddressDB.ModifiedBy]]!)

        array.append(EntityAddress(id: item[table[Id]], addressId: item[AddressId], entityId: item[EntityId], entityType: item[EntityType], address: address, isDeleted: item[table[IsDeleted]], created: item[table[Created]], createdBy: item[table[CreatedBy]] ?? 0, modified: item[table[Modified]], modifiedBy: item[table[ModifiedBy]] ?? 0))
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: If you look for `BookAuthorPair` in the [GRDB documentation](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) you'll surely find a very different approach to joins - and especially a way to write and reuse Address and EntityAddress initializers, even with joined rows...